# Laptop reboots instead of shutdown

Tags: shutdown, reboot

Since the upgrade to 18.04, my laptop often boots right back up after a shutdown. Almost killed it due to overheating as I transport and store it in a sleeve!

On further trial it seems to happen about every other time. A workaround is seeing if it reboots, and if so, shut down again from the login screen. It then usually doesn't reboot again.

A suggested workaround, using `sudo poweroff`, had the same unwanted behaviour in at least one instance.

Any idea how tk fix? Any log files I can provide that wid help?
The drive is encrypted.

Many thanks

Comment: Try using "sudo poweroff" to turn it off... It's not the full solution for your problem but it could be a temporary one.

Comment: Thanks @Ramuyko, I'll try that and let you know if it works as a workaround

Comment: I have the same problem, running gnome/xorg. `sudo poweroff` does *not* help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out it seems to be a wayland related problem. When I use xorg there is no problem, so, although I haven't been able to solve the problem, I have at least been able to narrow down and avoid its source.